# Gphoto2 - Canon Change Settings for Movie Recording Quality from HD to 4K

Tags: python, video, libgphoto2

I would like to change the settings of the Canon DSLR Camera from HD to 4K and vice-versa programmatically. I used gphoto2, libghoto2 to control the settings and capture photo and video. *(I have physically switched the nob to Video mode on camera)*

Camera Model: Canon EOS 5D Mark IV.

Camera settings on Camera look like below:

```
Movie Record Quality
 - MOV/MP4 
 - Movie rec. size  (MP4)
   -- FHD 50.00P IPB
   -- FHD 25.00P IPB
   -- FHD 25.00P IPB (Light)

 - Movie rec. size  (MOV)
   -- 4K 25.00P MJPG
   -- FHD 50.00P ALL-I
   -- FHD 50.00P IPB
   -- FHD 25.00P ALL-I
   -- FHD 25.00P IPB
```

The `gphoto2 --list-all-config` does not list these settings. Is there a way I can switch these using a script.

```
gphoto2 --summary
```

> Camera summary:
>   Manufacturer: Canon.Inc Model: Canon EOS 5D Mark IV   Version: 3-1.0.4
>   Serial Number: XxxxxxxX Vendor Extension ID:
>   0xb (1.0)
>
> Capture Formats: JPEG Display Formats: Association/Directory, Script,
>   DPOF, MS AVI, MS Wave, JPEG, CRW, Unknown(b103), Unknown(bf02),
>   Defined Type, Unknown(b104), Unknown(b105)
>
> Device Capabilities:  File Download, File Deletion, File Upload   No
>   Image Capture, No Open Capture, Canon EOS Capture, Canon EOS Capture 2
>     Canon Wifi support
>
> Storage Devices Summary: store_00010001:  StorageDescription: CF
>     VolumeLabel: None   Storage Type: Removable RAM (memory card)
>     Filesystemtype: Digital Camera Layout (DCIM)    Access Capability:
>   Read-Write    Maximum Capability: 32011124736 (30528 MB)  Free Space
>   (Bytes): 32010960896 (30528 MB)   Free Space (Images): -1
>
> Device Property Summary: Property 0xd402:(read only) (type=0xffff)
>   'Canon EOS 5D Mark IV' Property 0xd407:(read only) (type=0x6) 1
>   Property 0xd406:(readwrite) (type=0xffff) 'Unknown Initiator' Property
>   0xd303:(read only) (type=0x2) 1 Battery Level(0x5001):(read only)
>   (type=0x2) Enumeration [100,0,75,0,50] value: 100% (100)

Thanks again.